# GroupBy and Concatenate Rows

Tags: powerapps

I'm trying to group rows of a collection then concatenate a string column. Kindly see sample below. Maybe someone can point me to the right direction to tackle my predicament. Thank you.

Original Collection:

```
    ID Name
    1 John
    1 Tim
    2 Nikki
    3 George
    3 Rick
```

Target:

```
    ID Name
    1 John, Tim
    2 Nikki
    3 George, Rick
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be:

1. Use Distinct to create a column of distinct IDs
2. Use Concat to go from

   ```
   1 John
   1 Tim
   ```

   to

   ```
   1 John, Tim
   1 John, Tim
   ```
3. Use AddColumns to join both tables and you should get what you want.

There's likely some optimization and the above has not been tested. Here are some references on MS Docs to read more on these and see some detailed examples:

- [Concat, Concatenate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-concatenate)
- [Distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-distinct)
- [AddColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-table-shaping)